# Absolutely convergent sequence, but no measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A)$ a measure space, $\mu : \mathcal A \rightarrow (- \infty, \infty)$ a map with the following properties:

(i) $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$

(ii) For all pairwise disjoint families $(A_j)$ with $A_j \in \mathcal A$, $\sum \mu(A_j)$ converges absolutely and $\mu ( \cup A_j) = \sum \mu(A_j)$.

Then it does not necessarily follow that $|\mu|: \mathcal A \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is a measure. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu=\delta_1-\delta_0,$ were $\delta_x$ is dirac mass at $x$.

Then, $\mu$ clearly satisfies the given, but $|\mu|(\{0\})=|\mu|(\{1\})=1,$ while $|\mu|(\{0,1\})=|1-1|=0,$ so even finite additivity might fail.